# Rotating multiple objects to face from one vector to another

Tags: c#, math, rotation, angle

Currently, I have the player select 2 positions in the map, it's a 3d world but my problem is only relevant in the first 2 dimensions. I want to create a floor between the 2 selected points, and rotate them to the angle between those 2 points. https://i.stack.imgur.com/notT1.png (excuse my paint skills)

My code works properly in some cases, but in other cases the crates are spawned at the wrong angle. I think it has something to do with vec1.x > vec2.x, or something similar. But I can't figure it out.

What am I missing?

```
const int modelLength = 55;
const int modelWidth = 30;

void createFloor(Vector vec1, Vector vec2)
{
    float height = vec1.Z;
    float length = Math.Abs(vec1.X - vec2.X);
    float width = Math.Abs(vec1.Y - vec2.Y); 

    int crateWidth = (int)Math.Ceiling(width / modelWidth); 
    int crateLength = (int)Math.Ceiling(length / modelLength); 

    int adjustedWidth = crateWidth * modelWidth;
    int adjustedLength = crateLength * modelLength;

    double angleRad = Math.Atan2(adjustedWidth, adjustedLength);
    double angleDeg = Util.RadianToDegree(angleRad);

    Vector angles = new Vector(0, (float)angleDeg, 0);

    float mX = (vec1.X < vec2.X) ? adjustedLength / 2 + vec1.X : vec1.X - (adjustedLength / 2);
    float mY = (vec1.Y < vec2.Y) ? adjustedWidth / 2 + vec1.Y : vec1.Y - (adjustedWidth / 2);
    Vector middle = new Vector(mX, mY, vec1.Z);


    for (int i = 0; i < crateLength; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < crateWidth; j++)
        {
            float x = (vec1.X < vec2.X) ? vec1.X + i * modelLength : vec1.X - i * modelLength;
            float y = (vec1.Y < vec2.Y) ? vec1.Y + j * modelWidth : vec1.Y - j * modelWidth;    

            Vector v = new Vector(x, y, height);
            v = Util.RotateAround(v, middle, angleDeg);

            spawnCrate(v, angles); 
        }
    }
}

public static Vector RotateAround(Vector vectorToRotate, Vector center, double angleDeg)
{
    double angleRad = DegreeToRadian(angleDeg);
    double cosTheta = Math.Cos(angleRad);
    double sinTheta = Math.Sin(angleRad);

    return new Vector
    {
        X = (int)(cosTheta * (vectorToRotate.X - center.X) - sinTheta * (vectorToRotate.Y - center.Y) + center.X),
        Y = (int)(sinTheta * (vectorToRotate.X - center.X) + cosTheta * (vectorToRotate.Y - center.Y) + center.Y),
        Z = vectorToRotate.Z
    };
}
```

Thanks.